# Dynamically insert a row in an HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have three working bits of javascript that I'm trying to combine... unsuccessfully.  I'm trying to make it so when you click a button, it knows that two fields have the same entry.  If not, it will make another row in a table in my HTML with the information.

```
document.getElementById("goRow").addEventListener("click", check)

function check () {
  if (document.getElementById("firstName").value ==       document.getElementById("lastName").value){
    prompt('First name can not be last');
  }

  else {
    function newRow() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
      cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
      cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("email").value;
      cell4.innerHTML = " ";
    }
  }
```

Like I said, all the different parts work on their own, but I can't get them all to play nice with each other.

Comment: Like mentioned in the above comment; remove the `function newRow() {` and the closing `}` from the else statement.

Comment: You're also missing a closing brace `}` to close your `function check()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you trying to define a function as part of an ELSE condition? You should have that on its own, and call it from the ELSE:

```
function check() {
    if (document.getElementById("firstName").value == document.getElementById("lastName").value) {
        prompt('First name can not be last');
    } else {
        newRow();
    }
}

function newRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("email").value;
    cell4.innerHTML = " ";
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.  I was trying to define a function as part of a Else condition because it's only my 2nd week of Javascript.  Code works now, I upvoted your answer but it won't appear until I have more reputation  points.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload() {
  document.getElementById("goRow").addEventListener("click", check)
}

function check () {
  if (document.getElementById("firstName").value == document.getElementById("lastName").value){
    prompt('First name can not be last');
  } else {
    newRow();
  }
}

function newRow() {
   var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   var row = table.insertRow(1);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
   cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
   cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
   cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("email").value;
   cell4.innerHTML = " ";
}
```